# Как привязать Idea к GitHub после переустановки Windows?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, github

Я делал проект и загружал множество коммитов в репозиторий на GitHub
Затем пришлось переустановить Windows, все файлы и программы стерлись

Сейчас мне нужно добавить назад весь проект в папку Idea на компьютере и сделать привязку к уже существующему репозиторию на GitHub заново.

Проблема в следующем: я уже случайно "перезаписал" один из репозиториев, принудительно скоммитив туда просто тестовый файл. И теперь там вместо кучи коммитов - один, тестовый

Как можно:

1. загрузить все предыдущие коммиты в Идею (скачал с ГитХаб уже)
2. привязать заново репозиторий, чтобы продолжать коммитить туда же
3. скоммитить все файлы туда заново (т.к. если этого не сделать, они будут красным гореть и раздражать, а их очень много), не перезаписывая уже существующие коммиты по этим файлам
   ?

Comment: Привет! Уточните пожалуйста что за папка `idea`

Comment: 1 - клонировать репозиторий отдельно 2 - сделать hard reset главной ветки (предположим, что она у вас одна) на коммит до перезаписи репозитория одним файлом. 3 - принудительно запушить на гитхаб. 4 - если вносили какие-то изменения, то скопировать файлы в заново склонированный репозиторий, закоммитить, запушить. P.S. это при условии, что на гитхабе в репозитории история изменений сохранилась.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd <репозиторий-папка>
git init
git remote add origin <url>
git fetch
git reset origin/master
```

Применяется то же предостережение, это не будет работать, если у вас были изменения в других ветках, которые вы не отправили на свой remote (на самом деле они были потеряны, когда папка .git была удалена, но кто-то может знать об этом лучше, чем я), но он не сбросит ваши локальные изменения (если таковые имеются) в вашей локальной копии, поэтому вы можете затем добавить и зафиксировать их по мере необходимости.

Если у вас есть локальные изменения, которые вы хотите/должны сохранить, что бы вы ни делали, НЕ выполняйте `git reset --hard`